# I am getting null value while passing string from one view controller to another

Tags: objective-c, string, isnull

FirstView controller.

```
usernameTextField.text = [user objectForKey:@"name"];
strValue =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.usernameTextField.text];

if ([strValue isEqualToString:@""])
{
    NSLog(@"myString IS empty!");
    self.usernameTextField.text = @"";

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"FIRSTPAGE IS NOT empty, it is: %@", strValue);
    HomeViewController *homeVC = [[HomeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeVC];
    [homeVC setStr1:strValue];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:homeVC animated:YES];

}
```

second view controller

```
[super viewDidLoad];

defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSLog(@"Fetched STRING IS  %@!",strValue);

strValue =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.usernameLabel.text];

NSLog(@" STRING IS  %@!",strValue);


if ([strValue isEqualToString:@""])
{
    NSLog(@"myString IS empty!");

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Home string IS NOT empty, it is: %@", strValue);


}
usernameLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hi %@ !", strValue];
```

I am passing strValue of firstVC to SecondVC. I am getting my value in firstVC but secondVC in null while passing !!

**NSLog(@"Fetched STRING IS  %@!",strValue);**
Here ,I am getting NULL value.

Suggest me what is my mistake !

Comment: you are logging the value in `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: so, where should I write it ??

Comment: The variable's value might not have been passed when the view loaded

Comment: Also, how does `str1` relate to what you're printing?

Comment: it works Phillip.  Thank You both. Sasquatch and Phillip

Comment: For helping others with similar issue, please post answer to this question and accept it.

Comment: it work here is secondVC.                                                                                      [super viewDidLoad];       
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];

    defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  SecondVC:  
    NSLog(@"Fetched STRING IS  %@!",str1);
    
    usernameLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hi!  %@ ",str1];

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `[homeVC setStr1]` *before* you init the `UINavigationController`.  Like this:

```
HomeViewController *homeVC = [[HomeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
[homeVC setStr1:strValue];
UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeVC];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:homeVC animated:YES];
```

When you initialize the navigation controller it calls `-loadView` on its root view controller (which in turn triggers a call to `-viewDidLoad`).  In your code, this happens before you've set the string property, so the string is nil when `-viewDidLoad` is called.  Setting the property first will stop that from happening.